# Create nested table in PDF using PHP

Tags: php

I have generated PDF file using PHP by simple table. Now I want to create another table-2 in single Cell of table-1 using while loop. I am fetching records from Database. In following figure dotted line is table-2 and big table is table-1.

I wanted to look like -

```
____________________________________
|        |-------|----------|-------|
|        |-------|----------|-------|
|        |-------|----------|-------|
|        |-------|----------|-------|
|        |-------|----------|-------|
|        |-------|----------|-------|
 -----------------------------------|
```

```
$rt6=@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM proforma_invoice WHERE pro_invoice_id NOT IN (SELECT proforma_ref_id FROM tax_invoice) 
order by pro_invoice_id desc");
while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($rt6))
{   
    $this->Cell(20,6,$dateColumn,1);
    $this->Cell(20,6,$row['proforma_invoice_no'],1);
             
    $req=@mysql_query("select * from proforma_details where pro_ref_id='".$row['pro_invoice_id']."'");
    while($req1=@mysql_fetch_array($req))
    {
        $this->Cell(30,6,$i,1);
        $this->Cell(30,6,'-',1);
        $this->Cell(30,6,'-',1);
        
        $i++;
    }
    $this->Ln(); 
}
```

Comment: Don't use `@` to supress the errors and warnings !

Comment: thanks ..ok.. but say the actual ans regarding nested table in pdf file